# Transition between two UIViewControllers with no animation

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

From my appDelegate I load the the homeScreen ViewController like this:

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
[self.window setRootViewController:controller];
```

The app only ever then changes between my 'homeScreen' and 'PlayViewController' ViewControllers and that is done like this:

```
 PlayViewControlller* vc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PlayViewController"];
[self presentModalViewController:vc animated:NO];
```

and this

```
UIStoryboard* sb = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Storyboard" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *controller = [sb instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeScreen"];
[self presentModalViewController:controller animated:NO];
```

respectively.

This all works fine. I am able to switch between the viewcontrollers with uibuttons and the above code. However, I'm not sure what causes this, it happens after I've switched between the two viewcontrollers a few times, but the transition starts to get animated and they start twirling when switching.

Ok so I'm trying to narrow down the problem and see what's causing it. I think its the other animation blocks that I'm using in my app. But there's a lot there so don't know exactly what it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found the line of code that was causing this if anyone happens to find themselves in the same situation.

```
   [UIView beginAnimations:@"Move" context:NULL];
```